# Estimation of logit-normal parameters

Tags: distributions, estimation, logit

For $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$,

$$X = \frac{\exp(Y)}{1+\exp(Y)},$$

so $X$ has a logit-normal distribution. Then

$$\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp(2y)}{\left(1+\exp(y)\right)^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp{\left(-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)} dy $$

Can I express $ \mathbb{E}(X^2) $ as a function of $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

My goal is to estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ that maximize $ \left(\mathbb{E}(X^2)\right)^n $.

Comment: For fixed $n$ it suffices to maximize $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$, which makes it look a bit simpler. (Is this for some subject?) Note that if you want to maximize, you're probably going to want to take the derivative with respect to the parameters ... in which case it might even be possible to avoid actually doing the integral, or failing that, interchanging the order of differentiation and integration may yield a more tractable problem.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you already *have* expressed that expectation "as a function of $\mu$ and $\sigma.$" Indeed, for many purposes, an integral representation is an analytically useful tool.  Evidently you mean either some *particular form* of an analytical expression or perhaps some efficient numerical algorithm: could you describe which forms are desirable? (2) This question appears to have nothing to do with statistics: it's purely a data-free optimization problem.  What is the statistical problem you think this optimization will solve?