# Estimation of logit-normal parameters (II)

Tags: maximum-likelihood, logit-normal-distribution

This question is related to the below question.
[Estimation of logit-normal parameters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86359/estimation-of-logit-normal-parameters)

In the previous question, I showed only simple part of the whole problem.

The log-likelihood function that I would like to maximize is

$ n_1 log \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_1(y,\mu,\sigma) dy +
 n_2 log \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_2(y,\mu,\sigma) dy +
 n_3 log \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_3(y,\mu,\sigma) dy $

$n_1,n_2,n_3$ are known. $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are as follows.

$ f_1 = \frac{exp(2y)}{(1+exp(y))^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} exp(-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} )$

$ f_2 = \frac{exp(y)}{(1+exp(y))^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} exp(-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}) $

$ f_3 = \frac{1}{(1+exp(y))^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} exp(-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}) $

How can I find $\mu$ and $\sigma$ that maximize the above equation?